# "pythonic" way to fill bag of words

Tags: python, string, counter

I've got a list of words, about 273000 of them in the list `Word_array`
There are about 17000 unique words, and they're stored in `Word_arrayU`

I want a count for each one

```
#make bag of worsds   
Word_arrayU = np.unique(Word_array)
wordBag = [['0','0'] for _ in range(len(Word_array))] #prealocate necessary space
i=0
while i< len(Word_arrayU): #for each unique word
    wordBag[i][0] = Word_arrayU[i]
    #I think this is the part that takes a long time.  summing up a list comprehension with a conditional.  Just seems sloppy
    wordBag[i][1]=sum([1 if x == Word_arrayU[i] else 0 for x in Word_array])
    i=i+1
```

summing up a list comprehension with a conditional.  Just seems sloppy; is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: have you looked at using Counter from collections?  It's sole purpose is to give you a dictionary where the keys are the items from an iterable and the value is the count of those items from the iterable...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I like how we think....

Comment: `len([x for x in Word_array if x == Word_arrayU[i]])`

Comment: `len(filter(Word_arrayU[i], Word_array))`

Comment: If you're calling `np.unique` then wouldn't you remove all the duplicates anyway, meaning every count is 1?

Comment: _sum( x == Word_arrayU[i] for x in Word_array)_ will do the trick - Pytnon True and False may be used whenever _int_ type is used. That will probably save some execution time - but Counter approach still looks better

Comment: BTW, the main reason it's so slow is that your cycle is O(17,000*273,000) - for each unique word you scan the original list.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(Word_array)
the_count_of_some_word = counter["some_word"]

#printing the counts
for word, count in counter.items():
   print("{} appears {} times.".format(word, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using [*numpy.unique*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), just set *return_counts=True* in the unique call:

```
import numpy as np

unique,  count = np.unique(Word_array, return_counts=True)
```

That will give you two arrays, the unique elements and their counts:

```
n [10]: arr = [1,3,2,11,3,4,5,2,3,4]

In [11]: unique,  count = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

In [12]: unique
Out[12]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 11])

In [13]: count
Out[13]: array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the suggestion from @jonrsharpe...

```
from collections import Counter

words = Counter()

words['foo'] += 1
words['foo'] += 1
words['bar'] += 1
```

Output

```
Counter({'bar': 1, 'foo': 2})
```

It's really convenient because you don't have to initialize words.

You can also initialize directly from a list of words:

```
Counter(['foo', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

Output

```
Counter({'bar': 1, 'foo': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about most 'Pythonic' but definitely the easiest way of doing this would be to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

Word_array = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word1", "word2", "word1"]

wordBag = Counter(Word_array).items()
```

Comment: Terrible suggestion - count twice? If you - for some obscure reason - want tuples, _Counter(Word\_array).items()_ will do the trick

Comment: If you call a function over t the same data twice - that is bad practice. Since OP is talking about list of 237,000 words - yep, it is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 there is a built-in list.count function. For example:

```
>>> h = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c"]
>>> h.count("a")
3
>>>
```

So, you could make it more efficient by doing something like:

```
Word_arrayU = np.unique(Word_array)
wordBag = []
for uniqueWord in Word_arrayU:
    wordBag.append([uniqueWord, Word_array.count(uniqueWord)])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a less efficient (than `Counter`), but more transparent solution, you can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_counter = defaultdict(int)
for word in word_array:
    my_counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: why would he use defaultdict over Counter?